# HPTalx - program to communicate with HP48-50 calculators from Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, usb, hp

I searched this topic and found nothing so if my search-foo is bad....

HPTalx is the FOSS program to communicate with HP programmable calculators using Kermit.  IT is an invaluable program around here.

In anticipation of a company-wide upgrade, I upgraded this computer to Mate 16.04 LTS.  HPTalx died.

I've spent 3 days on it (hey, I'm an embedded systems engineer and not a Linux guru!) so it's now time to ask for help.  The program can be had here

```
https://www.hpcalc.org/hp48/pc/link/hptalx-1.3.0.tar.gz
```

It used to be in the repository until this upgrade.

During my debugging travels, I've found the following.  I suspect that the problem may be the upgrade from the revision to GTK3+.  I back-ported GTK2+ but that didn't have any effect.

I can see the calculator being enumerated and identified with both dmesg and lsusb so at least the physical level is working.  I can't see any evidence of the traffic making it past the physical layer.  Starting Kermit on the calculator and $ sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0 returns nothing even though I can see the calculator transmitting.

After each failure, HPTalx is locked.  It takes a kill -9 to kill it.  IT leaves behind a zombie ckermit in memory which also requires a -9 to get rid of.

I'm just about at my wit's end so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Comment: If you known calculators UART speed you can use `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` (115200 is speed in bytes/s) to test connectivity and get some info from it.